# Is the 'Subscriber Count' of a Publication List in Marketing Cloud the total number of 'Active' Subscribers?

Tags: marketing-cloud, publicationlist

When looking at a Publication List's "Subscriber Count" in Marketing Cloud, is the number shown the total number of emails within that Publication List, or the total number of emails with a Subscriber Status of 'Active'?

Answer (score 0):

The Subscriber count in the publication list is the number of subscribers present in the DE.

For Example: If you send an email to 5 subscribers using Data extension and Apply Test1 publication list with that send, those 5 subscribers will get added to that publication list.

Reference:
[Publication List](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_es_publication_lists.htm&type=5) 
[Subscribers on a Marketing Cloud Publication List](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_es_subscribers_on_publication_list.htm&type=5)

Comment: But if one of those 5 people unsubscribed from the Publication List off the back of an email, would they be counted with the total Publication List 'Subscriber Count' or would the 'Subscriber Count' now be 4, as that person is no longer subscribed to that Publication List?

Comment: Subscriber count will not change. Only subscriber status gets updated.